# GCC SDL + GLEW linking errors

Tags: opengl, gcc, sdl, glew

I have a static library in which I'm calling OpenGL extension functions via GLEW. As the project is being built in GCC (NetBeans 7.0), and GLEW's binaries are only shipped in Visual-C flavor, I have built GLEW (1.7.0) as a static library, with GCC. (I would also be interested why this is necessary, as GLEW seems to be pure C, in which ABI and cross-compiler compatibility isn't an issue AFAIK.)

In my static library I define GLEW_STATIC and NO_SDL_GLEXT as project preprocessor directives (-D), then I

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
```

The static library is then linked against in a (test) application, which also links against the following libraries, in the following order:

```
my_static_library
mingw32
glew32
opengl32
SDLmain
SDL
```

This setup gives me two undefined reference errors in my static library:

```
undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetStringi'
undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit'
```

Indeed, these are two calls made to GLEW functionality, in the static library. There are however other calls that the linker used to complain about (before -DGLEW_STATIC), yet seem to be ok now.

I wasn't able to improve the situation by swapping the order of linkage to opengl32 and glew32 (some more undef'd refs to `wgl...` calls). Furthermore, GLEW_STATIC (and NO_SDL_GLEXT) used to be defined in the test application but that has been removed and doesn't seem to matter.

Why do the remaining errors occur and what can I do to get rid of them, i.e. how can I use GLEW in GCC with SDL?

Comment: While the calling conventions are about the same, Visual-C links against another runtime standard library, as GCC, which are – unfortunately – incompatible. That's the main reason why you have to recompile with GCC.

Comment: No, mingw32 GCC links to the Microsoft's runtime libraries - `msvcrt.dll`, `kernel32.dll`, etc. It only uses import libraries in `ar(1)` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You library was built in such a way, as to link to the DLL version of GLEW - `_imp____glewGetStringi` and `_imp__glewInit` are import library symbols, i.e. the combination of defines resulted in the following line appearing when compiling;

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) PFNGLGETSTRINGIPROC __glewGetStringi;
```

This can happen if you don't define `GLEW_STATIC` while compiling your library (but you do; double check each object)

or

your version of GLEW has a bug in the headers. In GLEW 1.7.0 it works as expected.

Comment: Hi chill,

Thank you for your reply. I've got GLEW 1.7.0 (added this to the question) and I define GLEW_STATIC at a project level.

How can I have my project link against the static version of GLEW? And could you clarify what you mean by double checking each object? (The binaries?)

Comment: @iCE-9, when you get he unresolved external error, the linker should tell you the files, which contain the unresolved reference. Check the project log, to be sure that these files had `-DGLEW_STATIC` on the command line, used to compile them.

Comment: I've already had it added to the project defines, so that it's defined for each source file, and indeed, adding a #define GLEW_STATIC to the file that's triggered the linker error resulted in a "GLEW_STATIC redefined" error.

 Ironically, it was the objects that needed double-checking: after I got the redefinition error and removed GLEW_STATIC from the source code, it (re)compiled and linked fine... (yes, it'd been rebuilt before)